# Normalize numpy array to min max different form column min max

Tags: numpy-ndarray, database-normalization

I have a function that normalizes numpy array to min max values that are in the column itself :

```
def normalize_function(data):
   min = np.amin(data,axis=0)
   max = np.amax(data,axis=0)
   return (data - min)/(max-min)

Value = pdData[['wave1','value2','value3','wave3']].to_numpy()
Value = normalize_function(Value)
```

However, I need to preset my own min max values for each column separately.
Example :   for wave1  min=100  max=300,   for value2  min=2 max=10,   for value2   min=10 max=100. These min max values are different from min max values inside the column. Thanks is advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution so far. Add preset min max values to numpy array, normalize and then remove those added min max values.

```
# Normalization preset
normSetFile = "NormSet.xls"
normSetCsv = pd.read_excel(normSetFile)
normSetDF = pd.DataFrame(normSetCsv).astype(float)
npNormSet = normSetDF.to_numpy(dtype=np.float64)

def normalize_function(data):
min = np.amin(data,axis=0)
max = np.amax(data,axis=0)
return (data - min)/(max-min)

def norm_check(data):
for col in range(0, data.shape[1]):
    for ind in range(0, data.shape[0]):
        if (data[ind, col] < npNormSet[0, col]):
            print('Error    data ' + str(data[ind, col]) + ' at column ' + str(col) + ' index ' + str(ind) + ' is lower than min ' + str(npNormSet[0, col]))
        if (data[ind, col] > npNormSet[1, col]):
            print('Error    data ' + str(data[ind, col]) + ' at column ' + str(col) + ' index ' + str(ind) + ' is bigger than max ' + str(npNormSet[1, col]))

def Normalize(data):
norm_check(data)
data = np.append(data, npNormSet, axis=0)
data = normalize_function(data)
data = np.delete(data, slice(len(data)-2, len(data)), axis=0)
return data
```